# AEM Apache Dispatcher 2.4.6 client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, aem, dispatcher, sling

I have an AEM 6.3 instance running behind an Apache instance which version is 2.4.6, with Dispatcher module in it. All is good, but now I need to wipe out all query params for all URLs that end with ".html".

This may sound simple to accomplish, but I came across an issue I can't resolve. This is the rewrite rule I'm using to remove all the query params from URLs ending in .html:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1.html [QSD]
```

Technically, one could see this rewrite as not a rewrite actually, because it is sending the original request to the same URL, but the flag QSD is for dropping all query params.

The problem is, if I reload my Apache instance whit this rule included, I start getting errors like this:

```
[Wed Jun 10 14:53:35.698908 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 31733] [client 54.209.162.6:61649] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /etc/clientlibs, referer: https://my.domain.com/etc/clientlibs/mygroup/some/simple/page.html
```

I know some people had issues like this when migrating from Apache 2.2 to 2.4. This is not my case, and I have also checked my vhost configuration. I don't have directives from Apache 2.2 like "Order deny,allow" or "Allow from all". I'm using "Require all granted".

One weird thing in AEM logs, is that when my Rewrite rule is not in place, I can see error.log logging that "/etc/clientlibs/mygroup/some/simple/page.html" is found. But if I put the rule and reload Apache, I see this from logs:

```
10.06.2020 10:16:40.085 *INFO* [54.209.162.6 [1591798600081] GET /etc/clientlibs/mygroup/some/simple/page/jcr:content.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Resource /etc/clientlibs/mygroup/some/simple/page/jcr:content.json not found
```

It is like the extension .html would be ripped off from URL, and since there is no extension, AEM  or rather Sling is trying to use the default content resolver which is JSON.

Comment: are you sure this is the only rule you have?

Comment: I have many rules. But nothing for /etc/clientlibs. Also, for some others URLs ending in .html but without "/etc/clientlibs" the rules works perfectly.

Comment: what is the sling:resourceType of /etc/clientlibs/mygroup/some/simple/page/jcr:content?

Comment: It doesn't have sling:resourceType. It has jcr:primaryType = nt:resource. Just to be clear, in CRX, the exact path is /etc/clientlibs/mygroup/some/simple/page.html/jcr:content

Comment: Have you checked this? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

Comment: There is something weird. Apache's error says "client denied by server configuration: /etc/clientlibs". But "/etc/clientlibs" lives under my root Directory. This is my Directory config: https://pastebin.com/YZfbJLpk. The path "/etc/clientlibs" is exactly below "/data/apps/www/htdocs/mygroup". I think this is an Apache bug, where when you have certain redirect (like the one I put in my question) it makes think Apache that you are trying to access /etc/clientlibs instead of /data/apps/www/htdocs/mygroup/etc/clientlibs

Comment: @Perimosh  in your comment " But if I put the rule and reload Apache, I see this from logs:", is this the all rewriter rule or only this RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1.html [QSD] ?

Comment: I have found a fix. Thanks! I put the response in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to fix my issue. Even though I still don't understand the full picture. This is my final condition and rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1.html [QSD,PT]
```

Adding "PT" along with "QSD" makes Apache not return the "client denied" error. The condition around QUERY_STRING it is just to make sure Apache only manipulates those requests that really have query params in the URL, or technically at least one char

Answer (score 1):

why donÄt you just use

```
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,QSD]
```

(maybe the redirect is not needed in your case... but it makes things clear to the browser).

Or if you just want to make sure that your request is cached in the dispatcher and not passed throught to AEM each time, use:

```
/filter {
 /0001 { /type "deny" /method "POST" /url "/etc/*" }
 /0002 { /type "allow" /method "GET" /url "/etc/*" /query "a=*" }
}
```

in your dispatcher config (s. https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html for details).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The R is a good option, like you said, to make things clear to the browser. I will post what I had to do to fix my issues. Caching is not an option

Comment: I have found a fix. Thanks! I put the response in this post.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a conditional to skip this rule to be applied for /etc/clientlibs just before the rewrite rule. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc/clientlibs.*`

Comment: Thanks. I think I can't do that because of business needs. Look at my last comment in the question. Doesn't sound like a bug to you?

Comment: I will check if the Apache user has read/write/execution permissions in that path. Also, check the dispatcher log itself, to be sure it is not being filtered out.

Comment: I have found a fix. Thanks! I put the response in this post.